# Is this correct $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\mathrm dx\over (1+x^2)(\pi+\cos x)}=\color{red}1?$

Tags: integration

How may one show that

> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)(\pi+\cos x)} =\color{red}1\tag1$$

$x=\tan y$ then $\mathrm dx=\sec^2 y \, \mathrm dy$

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1+y^2} \cdot {\mathrm dy\over 1+\pi\sqrt{1+y^2}} \tag2$$

Comment: Your substitution looks wrong. Where did you find this integral, and why do you think it is equal to 1?

Comment: on my book and the answer one, but I am not it is 1

Comment: If you let $x=\tan y$, you will for sure have a term $\cos(\tan y)$ that looks difficult to get rid of.

Comment: [Wolfram can't seem to compute it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+-infty+to+infty+1%2F((1%2Bx%5E2)(%5Cpi%2B%5Ccos+x))+dx).

Comment: yeah you are right @mickep

Comment: What book are you using? And how much integration are you supposed to know before calculating this one? There are many ways for you to improve this question.

Comment: my note book, which I did awhile ago, I was sure how I got a 1

Comment: If $x=\tan y$ then $\cos x = \cos\tan y,$ and that doesn't look like anything in your integral with respect to $y.$ I wonder if you meant $y = \tan x$ rather than $x=\tan y. \qquad$

Comment: Your substitution leads to $$\int_{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{1}{\cos (\tan (y))+\pi } \, dy\approx 0.936259$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the integral doesn't integrate to $1$. The correct value is around $0.9352357$.

Since the derivation is a little bit messy, I will skip justification of most algebraic manipulations and test of convergence below. Furthermore, all sums of the form $\sum_n (\cdots)$ should be interpreted as $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N(\cdots)$.

Notice $\cos(x)$ is a periodic function of period $2\pi$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(\pi + \cos(x))}
&= \left( \sum_n \int_{(2n-1)\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\right)
\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(\pi + \cos(x))}\\
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sum_n \frac{1}{(x+2n\pi)^2+1}\right)\frac{dx}{\pi + \cos(x)}
\end{align}\tag{*1}
$$

Let $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$, $\alpha = \tanh\frac12$ and $\beta = \sqrt{\frac{\pi+1}{\pi-1}}$.

Start from the infinite product expansion of $\sin(x)$,

$$\sin(x) = x \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$
one can deduce
$$\cot(x) = \sum_n\frac{1}{x+n\pi}\quad\implies\quad
\frac12\cot\frac{x}{2} = \sum_n \frac{1}{x+2n\pi}$$
With a little bit of algebra, this leads to
$$\begin{align}\sum_n \frac{1}{(x+2n\pi)^2+1}
&= \frac{1}{4i}\left[\cot\left(\frac{x - i}{2}\right)
- \cot\left(\frac{x+i}{2}\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{4i}\left(\frac{1 + i \alpha t}{t - \alpha i} - \frac{1 - i\alpha t}{t + \alpha i}\right)
= \frac{\alpha}{2}\left(\frac{1+t^2}{t^2+\alpha^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Substitute this into $(*1)$, use the fact both $\cos(x)$ and above function is an even function and change variable to $t$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{I} 
&= \alpha \int_0^{\pi}\frac{(1+t^2)}{(t^2+\alpha^2)(\pi + \cos x)}dx
= \alpha \int_0^\infty
\frac{(1+t^2)}{(t^2+\alpha^2)\left(\pi + \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)}\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\pi-1} \int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{1+t^2}{(t^2+\alpha^2)(t^2+\beta^2)}dt
\end{align}
$$
Notice
$$\frac{1+t^2}{(t^2+\alpha^2)(t^2+\beta^2)}
= \frac{1-\alpha^2}{(t^2+\alpha^2)(-\alpha^2+\beta^2)}
+ \frac{1-\beta^2}{(-\beta^2+\alpha^2)(t^2+\beta^2)}$$

We find
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \frac{\pi\alpha}{(\pi-1)(\beta^2-\alpha^2)}\left[\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\alpha} - \frac{1-\beta^2}{\beta}\right]
= \frac{\pi}{(\pi - 1)\beta}\frac{1+\alpha\beta}{\beta+\alpha}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\pi^2-1}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi-1} + \sqrt{\pi+1}\tanh\frac12}
{\sqrt{\pi+1} + \sqrt{\pi-1}\tanh\frac12}\\
&\approx 0.93523570580939545599059373053102730519937591000461724...
\end{align}\tag{*2}
$$
As a double check, I have evaluated $\mathcal{I}$ numerically on WA using two equivalent form of the integral:

- `N[Int[1/((1+x^2)*(Pi+Cos[x])),{x,-Inf,Inf}],50]` gives
  $0.935197907462057583934216094872870832745553392068185$
- `N[Int[1/(Cos[Tan[y]]+Pi),{y,-Pi/2,Pi/2}],50]` gives
  $0.935221913498036727655246950920018882262473130195986$

One can see that our analytic result is compatible with the part where above two numerical methods agree ($\approx 0.9352$).

**Update**

It turns out there is an alternate (simpler?) way to evaluate this integral.

Pick a $\gamma > 1$ such that $\pi = \frac{\gamma^2+1}{2\gamma}$ (i.e. set $\gamma = \pi + \sqrt{\pi^2-1}$ ), we have

$$\frac{1}{\pi + \cos(z)} 
= \frac{2\gamma}{1+\gamma^2 + 2\gamma\cos(z)}
= \frac{2\gamma}{(\gamma + e^{iz})(\gamma + e^{-iz})}
= \frac{\gamma}{\gamma^2-1}\left[\frac{\gamma - e^{iz}}{\gamma + e^{iz}} + \frac{\gamma-e^{-iz}}{\gamma + e^{-iz}}\right]
$$
This leads to
$$\mathcal{I} = \frac{\gamma}{\gamma^2-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\left[\frac{\gamma - e^{iz}}{\gamma + e^{iz}} + \frac{\gamma-e^{-iz}}{\gamma + e^{-iz}}\right] \frac{dz}{1+z^2}\tag{*3}$$
On upper complex plane,

$$\Im z \ge 0 
\quad\implies\quad |e^{iz}| \le 1
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{\gamma - e^{iz}}{\gamma + e^{iz}}
\quad\text{ is bounded and analytic there.}
$$
On lower complex plane,
$$\Im z \le 0 
\quad\implies\quad |e^{-iz}| \le 1
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{\gamma - e^{-iz}}{\gamma + e^{-iz}}
\quad\text{ is bounded and analytic there.}
$$
We can evaluate the integral $(*3)$ by splitting what is in the square bracket
into two pieces. The first piece involving $\frac{\gamma - e^{iz}}{\gamma + e^{iz}}$ can be computed by completing the contour with a infinite large circle in upper complex plane and then taking residue at pole $i$ of $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$. Doing essentially the same thing to the second piece but in lower complex plane and taking residue at pole $-i$, we obtain:

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{I} 
&= \frac{\gamma}{\gamma^2-1}
\left[
\left(\frac{2\pi i}{2i}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma - e^{i(i)}}{\gamma + e^{i(i)}}\right)
+
\left(\frac{-2\pi i}{-2i}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma - e^{-i(-i)}}{\gamma + e^{-i(-i)}}\right)
\right]\\
&= \frac{2\pi\gamma}{\gamma^2-1}\left(\frac{\gamma - e^{-1}}{\gamma + e^{-1}}\right)
= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\pi^2-1}}\left(\frac{\gamma e - 1}{\gamma e + 1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Notice $$2\gamma = (\sqrt{\pi + 1} + \sqrt{\pi - 1})^2
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\pi+1} + \sqrt{\pi-1} = \sqrt{2\gamma}\\
\sqrt{\pi+1} - \sqrt{\pi-1} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi+1} - \sqrt{\pi-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\gamma}}\end{cases}$$

With a little bit of algebra, we can transform above result to
$$\mathcal{I}
= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\pi^2-1}}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi-1}(e+1) + \sqrt{\pi+1}(e-1)}{
\sqrt{\pi+1}(e+1) + \sqrt{\pi-1}(e-1)}\right]
= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\pi^2-1}}
\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi-1} + \sqrt{\pi+1}\tanh\frac12}{
\sqrt{\pi+1} + \sqrt{\pi-1}\tanh\frac12}\right]
$$
Reproducing what has been derived by another method.